# Restricting Access to Manager users - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am a newbie with Laravel. I am doing a tutorial and i have issues on restricting access to manager users. I have been able to assign roles (manager and members) to my users at the moment. But my issue lies in the Manager Middleware.

If the user is a manager, it doesn't return the `$next($request);` but instead it routes to `/home` after authentication and if user isn't a manager, it routes to `/home` as well instead of `/tickets`.

There is a file called `RedirectIfAuthenticated`, i changed the route in there but the issue still remained the same.

So what am i missing to restrict access to my managers?

**Manager middleware**

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {    
        if(!Auth::check())
        {
            return redirect('/login');
        }
        else{
            $user = Auth::user();
            if($user->hasRole('Manager'))
            {
                return $next($request);  
            }
            else{
                redirect('/tickets');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);      
    }
```

**Routes**

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' =>'manager'), function () {
    Route::get('users', 'UsersController@index');
    Route::get('users/{id?}/edit', 'UsersController@edit');
    Route::post('users/{id?}/edit','UsersController@update');

    Route::get('roles', 'RolesController@index');
    Route::get('roles/create', 'RolesController@create');
    Route::post('roles/create', 'RolesController@store');
});
```

Comment: there will be `Authenticated` function in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php` use same code there with some changes. redirect manager to his location and normal user to their location from here.

Comment: @AshishPatel, i am getting an error  `" undefined variable next"`

Comment: I have told you to make changes. `next` will not work there. you can just redirect users there based on their role.

Comment: `else{
                return redirect('/tickets');
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

in the else part: instead of `redirect('/tickets');` use `return redirect('/tickets');`

i.e. it will become:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {    
        if(!Auth::check())
        {
            return redirect('/login');
        }
        else{
            $user = Auth::user();
            if($user->hasRole('Manager'))
            {
                return $next($request);  
            }
            else{
                return redirect('/tickets');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);      
   }
```

That's it